# App Store Error This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription

Tags: objective-c, ios10

App store return this error three times also after adding the key to `info.plist` and localization strings file knowing that this app work on real device.

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
>   description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

For more information please review the below screenshot.

[image: Info.plist image]

Comment: Hi Mahmoud. Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share a screenshot of your `info.plist` file?

Comment: i had added a link for it

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?.

Comment: If your building ipa file with Xcode 8 and supporting to iOS 10, you have add privacy NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key and value, values is like what purpose are you using it in your app. Even though apple rejected app after adding the value also. Explain about the feature how would you using the Photo Library in the app by giving review comment through in iTuens.

Comment: Xcode 8 i just pick some images for adding aproduct to my app . ialso use localization in my app so  i added infoPlist.strings files and added the key to all of them i dont understand any reason for rejecting the app.

Comment: i think there is no need to add this in infoPlist.strings file. instead it should be added to info.plist file

Comment: Are you using an older version on AdMob? If you are, update to version 7.11.0 or later: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/download

Comment: @mahmoudelnagar you have to replace proper description with "Propertyturkey uses photos". Please add proper description for all permission

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error statement, you must add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key to your `info.plist` file.

At least i can not find the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in your `info.plist` file.

You can add it in your `info.plist` by adding following key: `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`.

The value of this key should be the description text that user will see when he is asked to authorize the app to access the photo library.

Something like this:
[image: NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist]

Here you can see `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` in red rectangle.

Hope this helps you or someone else.